# explanation of a certain code regarding watchdog timer in win ce?

Tags: windows-ce

I have code to run an inbuilt api for a watchdog timer on win ce. The different api's of watchdogtimer are to create it, refresh it, start and stop it.  I have some questions about the code itself, however.

```
header files

#include <windows.h>
#include <pkfuncs.h>
#define WATCHDOG_NAME L"wd_critproc"                    
#define WATCHDOG_PERIOD 5000 // milliseconds
#define WATCHDOG_WAIT_TIME 2000 // milliseconds
//WDOG_NO_DFLT_ACTION, WDOG_KILL_PROCESS, WDOG_RESET_DEVICE
#define WATCHDOG_DEFAULT_ACTION WDOG_RESET_DEVICE 
#define MAX_COUNT 10
```

What is the max_count used for in the code above?

```
main function

int wmain();
{
    HANDLE hWatchDogTimer=NULL;
    LPCWSTR pszWatchDogName=WATCHDOG_NAME;
    DWORD dwPeriod=WATCHDOG_PERIOD;
    DWORD dwWait=WATCHDOG_WAIT_TIME;
    DWORD dwDefaultAction=WATCHDOG_DEFAULT_ACTION;
    DWORD dwCount=0;
```

In the code above, what is dwCount used for?

```
    BOOL bRet=FALSE;

    wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Critical process start\r\n")));
    wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Calling CreateWatchDogTimer...\r\n")));
```

The Createwatchdogtimer api is being called here

```
    hWatchDogTimer = CreateWatchDogTimer(pszWatchDogName, dwPeriod,dwWait, dwDefaultAction,0,0);
    if (! hWatchDogTimer)
    {
        wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Invalid NULL handle, leaving app\r\n")));
        return 1;
    }
```

The code the checks for error already exists then same watchdog timer is not called

```
    if (GetLastError()==ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] WatchDog with this name already exists,leaving app\r\n")));
        return 1;
    }
```

Otherwise the watchdog timer is called

```
    wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Valid handle returned [0x%08x]\r\n")),hWatchDogTimer);
    wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Starting watchdog timer...\r\n")));
    bRet = StartWatchDogTimer(hWatchDogTimer,0);
    if (! bRet)
    {
        wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] StartWatchDogTimer failed GetLastError   returnedx\r\n")),GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hWatchDogTimer);
        return 1;
    }
    wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Watchdog timer started successfully\r\n")));
    dwCount=0;
    while ((dwCount++)<MAX_COUNT)
    {
          -refreshing watchdog timer      
        BOOL bRetVal=0;
        wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Refreshing watchdog timer... [%d]\r\n")),dwCount);
        bRetVal = RefreshWatchDogTimer(hWatchDogTimer,0);
        if (!bRetVal)
        {
           wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Failed to refresh watchdog timer,
            GetLastError returned 0x%x\r\n")),GetLastError());
           CloseHandle(hWatchDogTimer);
           return 1;
        }

        Sleep(1000);
     }

     wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Stopping watchdog timer refresh\r\n")));
     dwCount=0;
     while (++dwCount)              **-how does this loop work?**
     {
          wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] The watchdog should timeout in a few seconds... [%d]\r\n")),dwCount);
          Sleep(1000);
     }
     wprintf((TEXT("[critproc] Leaving app (should never be here)\r\n")));
     CloseHandle(hWatchDogTimer);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you related to [@SAJAN MISHRA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403927/can-anyone-debug-this-code-for-me-regarding-a-watchdog-timer-in-win-ce#comment41557407_26403927)?

Comment: Yes he is a friend of mine.He needed help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me point out that you need to do a better job of formatting code in your questions if you want people to help you out.  Lucky for you it's Monday and I was looking for a distraction from work I should be doing, so I formatted it for you.

As for your general questions, you need to look at this in broad terms of how a watchdog works.  This one appears to work somewhat like a named mutex.

1. The watchdog is created with a name.  If the selected name already exists, then a watchdog with the same name is already registered and the API returns an error (ALREADY_EXISTS) and the app terminates.
2. `MAX_COUNT` appears to be the number of seconds that the watchdog will be reset for.  Obviously this is just sample code for using the watchdog because this usage would be nonsensical in a real-world app.  Normally you'd have a background thread that infinitely resets the watchdog unless some fault condition occurs.  That what the first `while` loop in simulating.
3. Once the same app runs through the `MAX_COUNT` seconds, it goes into another loop.  That loop is for nothing other than the purpose of giving you `wprintf` feedback on what it's doing.  It will infinitely loop in there until the system watchdog fires, at which point the device will reset.

Comment: sorry for the format not being correct.i'm new to this and needed help desperately so.

Comment: next may i know what do you mean by "Obviously this is just sample code for using the watchdog because this usage would be nonsensical in a real-world app".

Comment: so how often will the refreshwatchdogtimer api will be called in the first loop?

Comment: will it be called until dwcount is less than max_count?

Comment: so if the system watchdog fires in the second loop how will it know when to come out of it?  does the sleep function help in any way cause i dont see any call to come out of the loop?

Comment: This is obviously a sample because normal operation will reset the device in roughly 10 seconds every time.  That's not what you would want in a fielded app.  Refresh is called in the first loop every 1000ms, for a count of 10 times.  Once Refresh is no longer called, the device is going to reset.  The app falls into the second loop and *never* exits it.  It will get into that loop and the device will reset when the watchdog timeout expires.  The Sleep call keep it from tight-looping and gives you feedback once per second that it's going to reset.

Comment: so technically the second loop is an infinite loop? is that how it is supposed to happen in a watchdog timer or should something be added in order to avoid the loop?

Comment: and obviously i dont want the device resetting the device every ten seconds.i want the timeout period to be 5 secs thats all.does this code help me do that?

Comment: if not can you suggest some changes. it'll be very helpful.thanks